# Tooltip left and right direction css

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I created a react component tooltip that should appear in the direction (top, bottom, left, right) passed into the component. When top or bottom is passed in it works fine, but when left or right is passed in, the tooltip will appear inside the element the tooltip is for instead of next to it.

react component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./toolTip.module.css";

const ToolTip = ({
  delay,
  direction,
  content,
  children
}: {
  delay?: number;
  direction: "top" | "right" | "left" | "bottom";
  content: any;
  children: any;
}) => {
  let timeout: any;
  const [directionClass] = useState(styles[direction]);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const showTip = () => {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setActive(true);
    }, delay || 400);
  };

  const hideTip = () => {
    clearInterval(timeout);
    setActive(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={styles.toolTipWrapper}
      onMouseEnter={showTip}
      onMouseLeave={hideTip}
    >
      {children}
      {active &&
        <div className={`${styles.toolTip} ${directionClass}`}>
          {content}
        </div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToolTip;
```

css

```
.toolTipWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 6px;
  color: rgb(217, 212, 212);
  background: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.toolTip::before {
  content: " ";
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.toolTip.top {
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.toolTip.bottom {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.toolTip.left {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.toolTip.right {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: A working example of the problem, presented as a codesandbox or other similar link, would be ideal, especially if cqb13's solution doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem.

```css
.toolTip.left {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: calc(-50% - 2px);
}

.toolTip.right {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: calc(100% + 2px);
}
```